# How to make a Score number grow bigger

Tags: c#

I want to make a mobile clicker Game in c#.
What I wanted to do here is that whenever the Player presses 10x Times the Button the Score grows from 1 Point for 1 click to 5 Points for 1 Click.

Here I have the Function `CountingClick()` that is connected to a trigger in Unity that counts the clicks the player is making and then I made an if statement that says if the clicked has the value 10 add 5 Points tho the Score. The AddScore() represents the Score.

I tried tho do this  with this script down there but the  if statement doesn't seem to work (clicked == 10){score = score + 5.0};

Does anyone know my error? Or does anyone has an idea of how it could work the other way?

This doesn't have anything to do with this Script but can someone tell how I could make that score builds himself up but if the Player stops clicking the Button for 3 Seconds the Score resets himself and you have to start from 1 Piont for 1 Klick again.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public double score;
    public double clicked;
    public Text scoreText;
    public Text Countext;

    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
        Countext.text = clicked.ToString();

        if (clicked == 10)
        {
            score = score + 5.0;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Test1");
        }
    }

    public void AddScore()
    {
       score = score + 1.0;
    }

    public void CountingClick()
    {
        clicked++;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read you code carefully. You are only increasing the score by 5 when you clicked 10 times. Instead of increasing the amount each click increases the score.

Comment: I cant see anything tracking whether the 10 x button was clicked

Comment: @MathewHD Yes thats right, do you know how i could do it on each Click?

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp The CountingClick() Function is connected with a trigger in Unity that activates evrytime the Button is pressed, so When the Player presses the Button the clicked value increases by 1 so now in a if Statement i ask if the clicked value is 10 and than in that if Statement i want something that increases the Score by evry Click , right now im just adding 5 Pionts to the Score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the `scoregain` for every 10 clicks you would need to add a `double` that represents the amount you add for each click.

**Counting clicks and increasing scoregain:**

```cs
private double scoregain = 1.0;

public void CountingClick() {
    // Increase clicked count by 1.
    clicked++;

    // Check if Button has been pressed 10 times since the last time.
    if (clicked >= 10) {
        scoregain++;
        // Reset clicked to 0, so it will be called again after another 10 clicks.
        clicked = 0.0;
    }
}
```

After that is done we can now increase the `score` with the `scoregain`. Instead of just by 1 each time.

**Increasing Score:**

```cs
public void AddScore() {
   // Increase score by scoregain amount.
   score += scoregain;
}
```